# Excel rounding issue when percentage from one cell is joined to an equation in different cell

Tags: excel

```
    A       B       C
-----------------------------------------
1   2014    0.576   2014 - 0.57555696
```

This is a pretty dumbed down version of what I am doing in C1
=SUM(A1)&" - "&SUM(B1)

Not sure how to make C1 keep the same rounding properties that were in place in B1. Tried using ROUND but could not figure it out.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=TEXT(A1,"0")&" - "&TEXT(B1,"0.000")
```

That will give you "2014 - 0.576" in C1, which is what I think you're wanting.  Is that right?